# Trouble calculating/understanding this surface integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, surface-integrals, parametrization, jacobian

Suppose $f\in C^3(\partial U)$ where $U \subset \mathbb R^3$ is an open, bounded and connected set with regular boundary. For some $s>0$ and $\epsilon>0$ sufficiently small, we define

$A_{\pm}:=\bigg \{x_0\pm t\frac{\nabla f(x_0)}{|\nabla f(x_0)|}\;,\;0\leq t \leq 2\epsilon\;,\;x_0\in\{f=s\} \bigg \}$

> We're interested in calculating $|A_{+} \cup A_{-}|$. The professor
> mentioned really quickly in class that
>
> $|A_{+} \cup A_{-}|=\int \limits_{\partial U} \int
>  \limits_{-2\epsilon}^{2\epsilon} J(x_0,t)\;dt\;dx_0\;\quad(*)\quad $ where $J$
> denotes the Jacobian transformation.

**QUESTIONS:**

1. I can not understand the formula in $(*)$. Shouldn't it be instead $|A_{+} \cup A_{-}|=\int \limits_{\{f=s\}} \int \limits_{-2\epsilon}^{2\epsilon} J(x_0,t)\;dt\;dx_0\;$? But still, how do we compute such an integral?
2. I know that when we compute an integral with parametrization, then a Jacobian will appear. However I don't see here which were the initial parameters in order to have a picture of what this Jacobian looks like. For instance, is it bounded? If so, does the regularity of $f$ play a role?

I am getting really puzzled when it comes to surface integrals. Maybe this is a silly question to make, but I am completely stuck. Any help is much appreciated.

Many thanks in advance!